# My system is unable to use Inter font on development server in next js?

Tags: next.js, google-fonts

[Inter Font Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1mMw.png)
`AbortError: The user aborted a request.
at abort (D:\LetsUpgrade-Work\LisA\lisa-student\node_modules.pnpm\next@13.4.1_@babel+core@7.22.9_@opentelemetry+api@1.4.1_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\node-fetch\index.js:1:65190)
at EventTarget.abortAndFinalize (D:\LetsUpgrade-Work\LisA\lisa-student\node_modules.pnpm\next@13.4.1_@babel+core@7.22.9_@opentelemetry+api@1.4.1_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\node-fetch\index.js:1:65410)
at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:778:20)
at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (node:internal/event_target:713:26)
at abortSignal (node:internal/abort_controller:369:10)
at AbortController.abort (node:internal/abort_controller:391:5)
at Timeout. (D:\LetsUpgrade-Work\LisA\lisa-student\node_modules.pnpm\next@13.4.1_@babel+core@7.22.9_@opentelemetry+api@1.4.1_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\node_modules\next\dist\compiled@next\font\dist\google\fetch-css-from-google-fonts.js:35:55)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
type: 'aborted'
}

- error Failed to download `Inter` from Google Fonts. Using fallback font instead.`

This is the error I am getting when i start my dev server and then it fallbacks to default font

pnpm i next/font/google